# Is it possible to setup SNMP trap settings on the NMS instead of the device itself?

Tags: snmp, snmp-trap

I know that I should setup the trap service on each devices seperately but I am just thinking about the possibility of setting up all devices in the network, by using the NMS.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does not look like a programming question. Probably belongs on ServerFault.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, it is technically possible to configure via NMS if,

- The vendor of this device provides the necessary objects in MIBs so that you can change via GET/SET.
- The default settings are suitable for you to perform initial connection in NMS.

Anyway you have to rely on the vendor (as there is no standard to cover this area), which is often frustrating.